# How to get the elements of a tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, stdtuple

I am creating a scrabble game and i need to have a basic score to words on the dictionary.

I used make_tuple and stored it inside my tuple. Is there a way to access elements in a tuple as if it was in a vector?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

void parseTextFile()
{
    std::ifstream words_file("scrabble_words.txt"); //File containing the words in the dictionary (english) with words that do not exist
    std::ofstream new_words_file("test.txt"); //File where only existing words will be saved
    std::string word_input;
    std::tuple<std::string, int> tupleList;

    unsigned int check_integrity;
    int counter = 0;

    while(words_file >> word_input)
    {
        check_integrity = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < word_input.length(); i++)
        {
            if((int)word_input[i] >= 97 && (int)word_input[i] <= 123) //if the letter of the word belongs to the alphabet
            {
                check_integrity++;
            }
        }

        if(word_input.length() == check_integrity)
        {
            new_words_file << word_input << std::endl; //add the word to the new file
            tupleList = std::make_tuple(word_input, getScore(word_input)); //make tuple with the basic score and the word
            counter++; //to check if the amount of words in the new file are correct
            std::cout << std::get<0>(tupleList) << ": " << std::get<1>(tupleList) << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << counter << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: No, `std::get` is how you do it. But maybe you want `std::pair` which has `first` and `second` members, or even an `std::map` to perform lookups?

Comment: Maybe `std::map` is what I need. With vector I would do it like: `for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << vector[i] << std::endl;
}`
I want to do something that performs the same but with tuples if that's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would generally use a [tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) when there are more than two values of different types to store. For just two values a [pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) is a better choice.

In your case what you want to achieve seems to be a list of word-value pairs. You can store them in a container like a vector but you can also store them as key-value pairs in a [map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). As you can see when following the link, an `std::map` is literally a collection of `std::pair` object and tuples are a generalization of pairs.

For completeness, if my understanding of your code purpose is correct, these are additions to your code for storing each tuple in a vector - declarations,

```
   std::tuple<std::string, int> correct_word = {};
   std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int>> existing_words = {};
```

changes in the loop that saves existing words - here you want to add each word-value tuple to the vector,

```
 if(word_input.length() == check_integrity)
 {
    // ...
    correct_word = std::make_tuple(word_input, getScore(word_input)); 
    existing_words.push_back(correct_word);
    // ...
 }
```

..and finally example of usage outside the construction loop:

```
for (size_t iv=0; iv<existing_words.size(); ++iv)
{
    correct_word = existing_words[iv];
    std::cout << std::get<0>(correct_word) << ": " << std::get<1>(correct_word) << std::endl;
}
std::cout << counter << std::endl;
```

The same code with a map would look like:

The only declaration would be a map from strings to values (instead of a tuple and vector of tuples),

```
std::map<std::string, int> existing_words = {};
```

In the construction loop you would be creating the map pair in a single line like this,

```
    if(word_input.length() == check_integrity)
    {
        // ...
        existing_words[word_input] = getScore(word_input);
        // ...
    }
```

While after constructing you would be accessing map elements using `.first` for the word and `.second` for the counter. Below is a printing example that also uses a for auto loop:

```
for (const auto& correct_word : existing_words)
    std::cout << correct_word.first << ": " << correct_word.second << std::endl;

    std::cout << counter << std::endl;
```

Notice that maps are by default alphabetically ordered, you can provide your own ordering rules and also use an [unordered map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) if you don't want any ordering/sorting.